# nodeJS ReferenceError : navigator is not defined.

Tags: node.js, rsa, public-key-encryption

Hello I'm trying to make some Javascript files working on nodeJS everything is well set however here is the error I get :

```
C:\>node myServer.js

C:\myFunctionsCallTest.js:750
if( (j_lm && (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")) || navigato
              ^
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myFunctionsCallTest.js:750:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myServer.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

C:\>
```

The files I'm using are :

```
myServer.js

var my_module = require("./myFunctionsCallTest.js");
console.log("RSA encrypted message :"+ my_module.Encrypt("myKey","myMessage"));

myFunctionsCallTest.js //This file contains some call of prototypes like : 
.....................................
RSAKey.prototype.setPublic = RSASetPublic;
RSAKey.prototype._short_encrypt = RSAEncrypt;
RSAKey.prototype.encrypt = RSAEncryptLong;
RSAKey.prototype.encrypt_b64 = RSAEncryptB64;
..............................................
```

Any idea from where this issue could come?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're using Tom Wu's BitInteger and RSA JavaScript library. This library was designed for use in the browser and doesn't work quite right in Node.js.

Luckily, someone has already gone through the work of packaging this library in a Node.js compatible format; it's on GitHub at https://github.com/eschnou/node-bignumber and available via npm as the package "bignumber", and comes with a nice [example](https://github.com/eschnou/node-bignumber/blob/master/example.js).